# Add extra processing in hibernate cascaded methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

How to add extra processing to be called whenever a cascaded operation such as save() is called? For example, if I have a Thing in the database with lots of Subthings, but some processing must be done before being stored (for example finding out today's date, and storing it in the column "create_date") and let's say this applies to every single database entry.

So when I save a Thing (using Jackson's objectmapper), it has some Subthings defined in the json, with the create_date being null (because we don't want the client to worry about that). But now when we save the Thing, hibernate cascade will only invoke the native hibernate save() on the Subthings, which means even though create_date processing will be done for the Thing, it won't be done for the Subthings, which means database will complain that the Subthings don't have any create_dates on them.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly trivial with Hibernate Interceptors (`org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor`). Here's a good example:

[Hibernate interceptor example - Audit log](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)